# memcached key naming

Tags: rest, memcached

I'm building a a rest service which uses memcached.
support my service handles:

```
GET http://server/books/6/pages?top=10&skip=5&sort=number
```

is it better to use the url as a memcached key? or should I build my own key string by concatenating the arguments in some way? e.g. "books_6_10_5_number". or maybe key can be a json representation of the arguments?

using the url is very easy. however if someone swaps the order of arguments there will be a cache miss.

the same question is also relevant for sql queries - should I store the sql as key or break it down to its arguments.

EDIT: as suggested, sorting would work for urls (though not for sqls). the question is more general: are there any other trade-offs in using the raw format (url, sql) vs. rolling my own format ("books_6_10_5_number")

Comment: You could sort the query string's values alphabetically?

Comment: @Yaron, looks like you already figured it out. You'll get cache misses if you directly use the URL as keys - put the parameters in an order that makes sense to your system first, most likely alphabetically as suggested by jackweird.